# How to scale text in Scribus along with the frame?

Tags: text, resize, scribus

I have a heavy InDesign background as I used it professionally for a number of years.  (CS 4 and CS 5, back in the day.)

I recently opened up Scribus again to see how far it has come.  (Last time I used it I found it extremely unintuitive with much missing functionality.)

One basic task I was hoping to do easily in Scribus is to visually lay out text on a page.  For example, put a header on a page in its own text box and then scale it visually to the size and width/height that I want.  In InDesign, this is easily done by holding down a key (I think it's Ctrl) while dragging the edges or corners of the text box, which makes the resizing apply to the contents of the text box along with the text box itself.

I tried Ctrl, Shift, Alt and various combinations thereof in Scribus (version 1.5.5) but couldn't produce this result.  I searched online for "Scribus scale text" and "Scribus resize text with frame" and found nothing useful.

Is this even possible in Scribus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 1.5.5 the Alt key should allow you to resize the content while resizing the frame.

I just tried it, and it just works.

Comment: Also works in 1.4.7 - just tested it too.  Also worth noting that 1.4.x versions are the stable releases, and that 1.5.x versions are developer versions, and probably more likely to contain bugs.

Comment: Thanks; my problem was solved by https://askubuntu.com/q/1189958/457111.

Comment: Yes, it's a good habit to leave the alt key free for graphics applications... It's sad that many distributions / setups still do not use the "win" key by default.